# CMake Error could not find Seperator

Tags: ros2, custom-message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
i try to compile my Package with `colcon build --packages-select sensor_interfaces`, to use my Custom Interface Messages. However i get follwing Error:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/humble/share/rosidl_adapter/cmake/rosidl_adapt_interfaces.cmake:59 (message):
  execute_process(/usr/bin/python3.10 -m rosidl_adapter --package-name
  sensor_interfaces --arguments-file
  /home/pi/gps/Python-GPS-m8p-d/ros2_gps_ws/build/sensor_interfaces/rosidl_adapter__arguments__sensor_interfaces.json
  --output-dir
  /home/pi/gps/Python-GPS-m8p-d/ros2_gps_ws/build/sensor_interfaces/rosidl_adapter/sensor_interfaces
  --output-file
  /home/pi/gps/Python-GPS-m8p-d/ros2_gps_ws/build/sensor_interfaces/rosidl_adapter/sensor_interfaces.idls)
  returned error code 1:

  Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
      return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rosidl_adapter/__main__.py", line 19, in <module>
      sys.exit(main())
    File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rosidl_adapter/main.py", line 53, in main
      abs_idl_file = convert_to_idl(
    File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rosidl_adapter/__init__.py", line 24, in convert_to_idl
      return convert_srv_to_idl(
    File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rosidl_adapter/srv/__init__.py", line 28, in convert_srv_to_idl
      srv = parse_service_string(package_name, input_file.stem, content)
    File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rosidl_adapter/parser.py", line 850, in parse_service_string
      raise InvalidServiceSpecification(

  rosidl_adapter.parser.InvalidServiceSpecification: Could not find separator
  '---' between request and response

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/humble/share/rosidl_cmake/cmake/rosidl_generate_interfaces.cmake:130 (rosidl_adapt_interfaces)
  CMakeLists.txt:16 (rosidl_generate_interfaces)
```

This is the CMakeList:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(sensor_interfaces)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
# uncomment the following section in order to fill in
# further dependencies manually.
# find_package(<dependency> REQUIRED)
find_package(rosidl_default_generators REQUIRED)


rosidl_generate_interfaces(${PROJECT_NAME}
  "msg/GPSFix.msg"
  "msg/GPSStatus.msg"
  "srv/AddThreeInts.srv"
)

if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
  # the following line skips the linter which checks for copyrights
  # comment the line when a copyright and license is added to all source files
  set(ament_cmake_copyright_FOUND TRUE)
  # the following line skips cpplint (only works in a git repo)
  # comment the line when this package is in a git repo and when
  # a copyright and license is added to all source files
  set(ament_cmake_cpplint_FOUND TRUE)
  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()

ament_package()
```

package.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format3.xsd" schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>

<package format="3">
  <name>sensor_interfaces</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>TODO: Package description</description>
  <maintainer email="72839268+GeneralBombe@users.noreply.github.com">pi</maintainer>
  <license>TODO: License declaration</license>

  <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>
  
  <build_depend>rosidl_default_generators</build_depend>

  <exec_depend>rosidl_default_runtime</exec_depend>

<member_of_group>rosidl_interface_packages</member_of_group>
  <test_depend>ament_lint_auto</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_lint_common</test_depend>

  <export>
    <build_type>ament_cmake</build_type>
  </export>
</package>
```

Environmental Variables:

> ROS_VERSION=2 ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=3
> ROS_LOCALHOST_ONLY=0 ROS_DISTRO=humble

gcc (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1) 11.2.0

[Here](https://github.com/GeneralBombe/Python-GPS-m8p-d/tree/main/ros2_gps_ws/src/sensor_interfaces) is the Package in my GitHub Repo.
I'd appreciate any help :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/406422/cmake-error-could-not-find-seperator/) by [MysticKnight](https://answers.ros.org/users/117850/mysticknight/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-09-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, have you tried looking into this website [Link](https://discourse.cmake.org/t/missing-separator-error/4947)

---

Originally posted by [faisalam1n](https://answers.ros.org/users/117922/faisalam1n/) with karma: 16 on 2022-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0